# How can I use a flag variable for user to end his input

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of Integer which will be filled by user, I want to take the input till the user wants. How can I do that?

I've tried this but didn't satisfy me. where s is the end token for user.

```
for(int i=0;input.nextInt()!='s';i++)
{   int a=input.nextInt();
    number.add(a);
}
```

Comment: `nextInt()` will probably make more sense when compared to an integer instead of a char. Except if you explicitly want this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `nextInt()` will not solved your problem since it will generate an exception once the user inputs a non integer, thus your loop condition will never be executed. Also you should just use a `while` loop instead of using a `for` loop since your iteration count is unknown. I have modified your code. Refer to the code and code comments below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
        String endToken = "s"; // this will be the holder of your end token
        while (true) { // iterate while user doesn't input the end token
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter an integer or enter 's' to exit!"); // ask the user for input
                String userInput = input.nextLine(); // get the user input
                if (userInput.equals(endToken)) { // check if user input is end token
                    break; // exit the loop
                }
                int a = Integer.parseInt(userInput); // convert the input into an int
                number.add(a); // add the input to the list
             // if an error inputs a String but not the end token then an exception will occur
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input!"); // tell the user that the input is invalid and ask the input again
            }
        }

        input.close(); // don't forget to close the scanner

        // loop below is just used to print the user inputs
        System.out.println("Your inputs are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is this `while (true)`? It will create an infinite loop.

Comment: It won't create an infinite loop because once the user inputs the ```endToken``` the loop will exit.

Comment: Ok, I missed that

Comment: @Mehrose you can check my solution. And if it solved your problem don't forget to mark it as the correct answer and/or upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Regex to parse the input passed, the solution will exclude the floats and strings

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> userNumber = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\d");
    Matcher m = null ;

    System.out.println("Enter your number list use chanracter 'NO' or 'no' as the terminator: ");
    String input = s.nextLine();
    String[] data = input.split(",");
    for(String word : data) {
        if(word.equals("NO") || word.equals("no")) {
            break;
        }
        //m = p.matcher(word).matches();
        if(p.matcher(word).matches()) {
            m = p.matcher(word);
            m.find();
            int n = Integer.valueOf((m.group()));
            userNumber.add(n);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Data entered " + word + " is not a number : ");
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Numbers entered are : " + userNumber);

}
```

Input

```
12,12.1,123,"asd",123,"NO","NO"
```

Output

```
Data entered 12.1 is not a number : 
Data entered "asd" is not a number : 
Data entered "NO" is not a number : 
Data entered "NO" is not a number : 
Numbers entered are : [12, 123, 123]
```

Comment: Input a non integer and ```InputMismatchException``` will occur

Comment: @Mehrose can you please share the input you are trying... I might not be getting the question right

Comment: It will result to an incorrect output. Input the following: ```12,12.1,123,"asd",123,"NO","NO"``` expected result is ```[12,123,123]```, your result is ```[12]```